# wp_signon works local, not on https

Tags: php, server

On my localhost environment the following code works perfect

```
    $creds['user_login'] = $user_login;
    $creds['user_password'] = $user_password;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, true );
    if(!is_wp_error($user)) {
        wp_redirect('/home');
        exit;
    }
```

But on the server it doesn't work anymore. The user is never logged in.
The website is hosted on a https subdomain on an external server.

I tried setting a cookie domain in my wp-config:

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '.domain.com');
```

And also with the subdomain included:

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', 'sub.domain.com');
```

Neither worked for me.

The server runs on PHP 7.1 with Varnish.
Swift Performance is used for caching.

Comment: Can you use your browser's debug tools to look for the 'Set-Cookie' response header you're getting on login, and work out why that's wrong?

Comment: There are no cookies at all in the response headers on the server. In the localhost environment I see some session cookies being set.... Do you might know if this is a server problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Varnish was the problem.

Varnish removes cookies from the response. That's why it didn't work in our case!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the auth cookie after wp_signon. Add this code and try and let me know the result.

```
$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );

$userID = $user->ID;

wp_set_current_user( $userID, $creds['user_login']  );
wp_set_auth_cookie( $userID, true, false );
do_action( 'wp_login',$creds['user_login']  );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I add do_action( 'wp_login',$creds['user_login']  ); the website crashes.. The code without do_action also doesn't work.

Comment: is the page that runs wp_signon cached in any way? Do you have a cache plugin or something like Cloudflare sitting in front of it?

Comment: try turning on debuglog file from wp-config and check what errors you have try adding exit() below wp_signon

Comment: The [wp_login hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_login/) takes two arguments: user ID and the user object. But wp_signon already calls it, and [the wp_signon docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_signon/) say that it sets the cookie too.

Comment: @TejasGajjar We use Varnish and Swift Performance. But Swift performance doesn't cache this page.

Comment: Have you try to generate debug file?